# Need to update a table with the timestamp when the data in another column is updated

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column where it gets updated with todays date when the SSIS package complete. But the thing is I need to capture the time and date at which the column gets updated to todays date into another table with help of trigger

Comment: And what is your question exactly ?

Comment: so write a `after trigger`, what is the problem with this.

Comment: So what's your question? You've stated what you want, but that's it. If you know what you need to do, you don't need our permission to do so; but if you feel you need it, you have mine.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a SQL Server TRIGGER to update the timestamp after update to your "key" column.  Making the timestamp column have a default of "getdate()" will handle the inserts.